# How to Capture / Post system-wide Keyboard / Mouse events under Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos

For a scripting utility I need to be able to record a series of keyboard and mouse events that occur when an application has focus. The second part is being able to later send those events to the active window.

I do not need to worry about menus or tracking the identifier of which window receives input.

I know how to do this under Windows but have no idea about Mac OS X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing i will tell you is that you *CAN'T* do this without the user enabling support for assitive devices in the accessability control panel.  It's some kind of security built into OSX.

Here is a code snippit I am using in one of my applications to do this:

```
//this method calls a carbon method to attach a global event handler
- (void)attachEventHandlers
{
    //create our event type spec for the keyup
    EventTypeSpec eventType;
    eventType.eventClass = kEventClassKeyboard;
    eventType.eventKind = kEventRawKeyUp;

    //create a callback for our event to fire in
    EventHandlerUPP handlerFunction = NewEventHandlerUPP(globalKeyPress);

    //install the event handler
    OSStatus err = InstallEventHandler(GetEventMonitorTarget(), handlerFunction, 1, &eventType, self, NULL);

    //error checking
    if( err )
    {
        //TODO: need an alert sheet here
        NSLog(@"Error registering keyboard handler...%d", err);
    }

    //create our event type spec for the mouse events
    EventTypeSpec eventTypeM;
    eventTypeM.eventClass = kEventClassMouse;
    eventTypeM.eventKind = kEventMouseUp;

    //create a callback for our event to fire in
    EventHandlerUPP handlerFunctionM = NewEventHandlerUPP(globalMousePress);

    //install the event handler
    OSStatus errM = InstallEventHandler(GetEventMonitorTarget(), handlerFunctionM, 1, &eventTypeM, self, NULL);

    //error checking
    if( errM )
    {
        //TODO: need an alert sheet here
        NSLog(@"Error registering mouse handler...%d", err);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the callback method i am using:

```
OSStatus globalKeyPress(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef theEvent, void *userData) 
{
    NSEvent *anEvent = [NSEvent eventWithEventRef:theEvent];
    NSEventType type = [anEvent type];
    WarStrokerApplication *application = (WarStrokerApplication*)userData;

    //is it a key up event?
    if( type == NSKeyUp)
    {
        //which key is it?
        switch( [anEvent keyCode] )
        {
            case NUMERIC_KEYPAD_PLUS: 
                //this is the character we are using for our toggle
                //call the handler function
                [application toggleKeyPressed];
                break;

                //Comment this line back in to figure out the keykode for a particular character                
            default:
                NSLog(@"Keypressed: %d, **%@**", [anEvent keyCode], [anEvent characters]);
                break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextEventHandler(nextHandler, theEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For the latter part, posting events, use the CGEvent methods provided in ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h

Here's an example function to move the mouse to a specified absolute location:

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int to(int x, int y)
{
    CGPoint newloc;
    CGEventRef eventRef;
    newloc.x = x;
    newloc.y = y;

    eventRef = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, newloc,
                                        kCGMouseButtonCenter);
    //Apparently, a bug in xcode requires this next line
    CGEventSetType(eventRef, kCGEventMouseMoved);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, eventRef);
    CFRelease(eventRef);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For tapping mouse events, see [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161752/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/altermouse/)

I haven't checked this under 10.5 Leopard but on 10.4 it works.

Comment: Works for keyboard events, too, but (IIRC) the user must enable access for assistive devices in System Preferences.

Comment: Addendum: My previous comment refers only to keyboard event taps. Mouse event taps are always available (again, IIRC).