# How to prevent/change system-wide Keyboard / Mouse events under Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I find two method to handle global events on Mac OS:

1. NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents only get a copy of origin event, can monitor, but not change or prevent.
2. Use InstallEventHandler like the answer at [How to Capture / Post system-wide Keyboard / Mouse events under Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399616/how-to-capture-post-system-wide-keyboard-mouse-events-under-mac-os-x) question. But only GetEventMonitorTarget() work, so I only monitor events。

So, How to prevent/change the system-wide events ? The KeyboardCleanTool app (http://blog.boastr.net/?p=2452) can do like that, so I think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Quartz Event Taps](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1658572-quartz_event_services?language=objc) for that. In order to monitor/change/block keyboard events, your process will need to be trusted for Accessibility access.